# One Plus One Boot Loop - Marshmallow Update

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, boot-loop, oneplus-one

today I updated my OnePlus One to Android 6.0.1 Cyanogenmod. It is now stuck in a boot loop, it turns on, runs for approximately two minutes, freezes, then restarts.

My phone is not rooted.

Here are my phones details.

Model: A0001

6.0.1

Cyanogen Version: 13.0-ZNH0EAS2JK

Cyanogen API: Dragon Fruit (4)

Kernel: 3.4.110

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please start having a look at our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) and follow the first-aid given there. Then come back here and either [answer your own question](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if solved, or [edit] it and add what you've tried, how it failed, and where you're stuck. Good luck!

Comment: Press the power button repeatedly for number of times to get it to working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory Restart was the only solution.